# If the chart is only one, it occupies the entire free space

Tags: jquery, charts, jqplot

I need to plot a graph in the form of horizontal charts showing some value in percentage.
I made a charts, but there is one problem.

When on the graph a few charts they look normal.
[image]

But when the chart only one, it occupies all the free space. 
[image]

How to make the chart look a little smaller, leaving place for the label?

And I think that if the value is 20%, as in the second screenshot, then the x-axis length should be more than 20%.

My code below

```
$.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
window.charts = {};

if ($('#summaryChart').length > 0) {
    var minimal_data_charts = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < minimal_data.length && i < 10; i++) {
        minimal_data_charts[i] = [minimal_data[i].persent, i+1, minimal_data[i].passenger];
    }

    $('#summaryChart').css('font-size', '15px');
    window.charts.summaryChart = $.jqplot('summaryChart', [
        minimal_data_charts], {
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            pointLabels: { show: true, location: 'e', edgeTolerance: -15 },
            shadowAngle: 135,
            rendererOptions: {
                barDirection: 'horizontal'
            }
        },
        axes: {
            yaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 110,
                    numberTicks: 12
                }
```

Сode above solved my x-axis problem.

Code below makes the chart a bit smaller by the y-axis

```
    rendererOptions: {
        barDirection: 'horizontal',
        barMargin: 50
    }
```

But barMargin: 50 should be not always, if only one chart is displayed.